# MySQL : Does 'bytes_sent' and 'bytes_received' include mysqldump data?

Tags: mysql, replication, backup, mysqldump, mysql-5

I'm trying to estimate my db traffic not including backups (mysql 5.1.41).

I use `show global status;` to get the parameters `bytes_sent` and `bytes_received`.

Questions

- Do these numbers include mysqldump (backup) data or not ?
- Do they include the log file which is being read by slaves or not?

Thanks,
Niro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do these numbers include mysqldump (backup) data or not ?

It would include mysqldump for one simple reason: It uses a DB Connection. That DB Connection, when you do `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`, has a `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` running on a table at any given moment during the mysqldump.

> Do they include the log file which is being read by slaves or not?

In MySQL Replication, you have two threads: IO Thread and SQL Thread. They are, for all intents and purposes, DB Connections as they are counted (included) under the global status variable `Threads_created`. DB Connections and Threads are really one and the same.

What then gets counted?

- Bytes sent : IO Thread requesting binlog entries from the Master
- Bytes recevied : IO Thread reading binlogs entries from its Master
- Bytes recevied : SQL thread reading its own relay logs