# Determining replication traffic

Tags: mysql, replication

is there any way to determine from server statistics* running MySQL, how much traffic(bits per second) WOULD replication consume between 2 servers, without setting-up the actual replication between those 2 servers ?

*Statistics = mysql commands over time, Disk IO per second, traffic, ram cpu...(e.g. CollectD rrd data)

Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Apri 18, 2012, I addressed a similar question : [MySQL : Does 'bytes_sent' and 'bytes_received' include mysqldump data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16697/mysql-does-bytes-sent-and-bytes-received-include-mysqldump-data/16705#16705)

I mentioned the following

- [Bytes_sent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_sent) : IO Thread requesting binlog entries from the Master
- [Bytes_received](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_received) : IO Thread reading binlogs entries from its Master
- [Bytes_received](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_received) : SQL thread reading its own relay logs

You can find out what these are for all connections past and present by doing

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name IN ('Bytes_received','Bytes_sent');
```

You can do so an individual session by doing

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.session_status
WHERE variable_name IN ('Bytes_received','Bytes_sent');
```

I have good news and bad news. First ...

## BAD NEWS

You cannot get a SQL thread to query `information_schema.session_status`. That's a violation of the first and fifth amendments (if applied against Replication's SQL thread).

## GOOD NEWS (Sort of)

The only way you can track any kind of byte traffic is to do the following

- Enable Binary Logging on the Slave
- Dump all binlogs on the Slave using

  mysqlbinlog --server-id=(server_id of the Master) ... > Binlogs_From_Master.txt
- Take the filesize of `Binlogs_From_Master.txt` and that's your best guess.

Subtract that filesize from whatever `Bytes_received` is, and that's the internal byte traffic on the Slave.

## CAVEAT

You will have to set up replication to find that number out.

As an alternative, you could just use one the the following from the Master

- [Bytes_sent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_sent)
- [Bytes_received](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_received)
- [Bytes_sent](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_sent) + [Bytes_received](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Bytes_received)

as an educated guess.

## Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thank you for excellent answer. I reviewed how does MySQL replication work and (1.)it seems that for a rough guess of how much traffic will replication consume I can use: EST=size(BINLOG) x NUMBER_OF_SLAVES, am I partly correct or completely wrong ?:) (2.) SHOW GLOBAL bytes_sent on master can not be used if I have no slave hosts, can it ?